# Detect contours of flies on a white background (sticky trap) that leaves some gray smudges

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

So i am trying to detect the contours of flies on a white trap, and after to crop these into different photos. But i am getting the contours of smudges on the trap and some flies are not detected.
Also i don't need the green color lines of the trap. 
My question is there any way to make sure i get the contours of all the flies and only the files?

code:

```
image = cv2.imread('test3.jpeg') 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)  
cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
```

example image

[image]

result with current code

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Have you tried Hough transform to find the lines and then subtract them from the final mask? The remaining will be the flies and some smudges hopefully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use convert color space to HSV and morphology operations:

```
import cv2

img1 = cv2.imread('flys.jpg')
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (6,6))
img=cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask=cv2.threshold(img1[:,:,2], 85, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1] 
mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations = 2)
mask = cv2.erode(mask, kernel, iterations = 7)

mask=cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
output = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(mask, 4, cv2.CV_32S)
print('number of flies: ', output[0])
for i in range(1, output[0]):
    x,y,w,h,s=output[2][i]
    img_crop=img1[y:y+h, x:x+w,:]
    cv2.imwrite(str(i)+'_crop_fly.jpg', img_crop)
mask=cv2.cvtColor(mask,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)


mask[:,:,1]=0
dst = cv2.addWeighted(img1, 0.7, mask, 0.3, 0.0)
cv2.imshow('test', dst)
cv2.imwrite('out_fly.jpg', dst)
```

[image]

Comment: wow thank you! Can yo maybe explain a little bit more what you did there? or maybe some source that explains better?

Comment: also how could i count the number of flies with this code? and crop the flies to different images?

Comment: I change my code. Add crop the flies to different images.

Comment: And add output numbers of fly.
The way to solve this problem is color transformations and mathematical morphology. There are many books on digital image processing. 
P.S. Sorry, I don't know English very well. :-(